# is it viable to pump water with wind before turning it into electricity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, renewable-energy

If one was to place many [short] turbines along a windy bridge, a levee or a windy road could one remedy the losses from many small generators, low voltage and large distances by pumping water in stead?

(A bit like a modern version of the aqueduct without it being a means of transportation.)

I was thinking of 2 versions:

1) a double tube where each turbine pumps water from one (lower?) into the other.

2) a single loop where a propeller in the tube is directly driven by the turbine axle.

How would losses compare with electricity over distance?

(I know I've failed to provide many details but feel free to fill in the blanks with constructive imagination.)

Comment: What is the goal? To move water a long distance, or to generate electricity?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to just ignore all the details of your the mechanics you suggest/propose in your description and just focus on your main question in the title - because 'how' you might do it is better addressed in an engineering forum.

And from a pure physical perspective the answer is - it depends. It really depends on how much energy you have available from wind at the location you intend on utilizing it, converting it to energy that can pump the water against forces of gravity and viscous friction.